# Need to create a Third list in Visual Basic from Two Lists

Tags: vb.net

I have three lists. List1 is AllTimeSlots. List 2 is BookedTimeSlots and List 3 AvailableSlots. List3 is the list that I want to populate to show the available slots, which is the difference between List 1 and List 2. I have tried comparing List 2 by traversing it using an if statement. I am trying to ccompare each element - if Element(1) from AllTimeSlots is not equal to any of the elemnents in Booked TimeSlots, then I want to populate the New list (AvailableTimeSlots) with Element(1). I then move onto to the next iteration.

'String Object used to display the elements from the available time slots list
Dim DisplayList As String = " "

```
    'Here is a list of all time slots
    Dim AllTimeSlots As New List(Of String) From {"08h00-09h00", "09h00-10h00", "10h00-11h00", "11h00-12h00", "12h00-13h00",
                                                   "13h00-14h00", "14h00-15h00", "15h00-16h00", "16h00-17h00", "17h00-18h00",
                                                   "18h00-19h00", "19h00-20h00", "20h00-21h00", "21h00-22h00", "22h00-23h00",
                                                   "23h00-24h00"}


    'Here is a list of the booked time slots
    Dim BookedTimeSlots As New List(Of String) From {"08h00-09h00", "10h00-11h00", "12h00-13h00", "16h00-17h00", "18h00-19h00"}

    'Here is the list which I want to populate after comparing the two lists to filter out the booked time slots
    Dim AvailableTimeSlots As New List(Of String) From {" "}

    'Here is the loop i am using to try filter out booked time slots and put the available ones into the empty list declared above 
    For i As Integer = 0 To AvailableTimeSlots.Count - 1 Step 1
        If Not BookedTimeSlots(i) = AllTimeSlots(i) Then

            'if element(1) from AllTimeSlots is NOT equal to any of the elemnents in Booked TimeSlots, 
            'then I want to populate the New list (AvailableTimeSlots) with element(1). I then move onto 
            'to the next iteration.

            AvailableTimeSlots.Add(i)

        End If
    Next

    'here i am trying to display the available elements into a listbox
    For Each elem As String In AvailableTimeSlots
        DisplayList &= elem & " "
        ListBox5.Items.Add(DisplayList)
    Next
```

Comment: [Enumerable.Except](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: ListBox.Items.Add(AvailableTimeSlots)

Comment: In the above, I manually populate the time slots: BookedTimeSlots As New List(Of String) From {"08h00-09h00", "10h00-11h00", "12h00-13h00", "16h00-17h00", "18h00-19h00"}. I am trying to populate the BookedTimeSlots Object from my database with the method. DTCurrentBookingsTableAdapter.FillObject(DsEventBooking13.DTCurrentBookings,
                                                                                                  MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString) .

Comment: I am getting "0 " being returned instead of the time slots in the SQL query. My query returns the desired time slots.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```vb
Dim AvailableTimeSlots = AllTimeSlots.Except(BookedTimeSlots)
```

Do **NOT** call `ToList()`. Let this variable remain typed as an IEnumerable(Of String), so that it's current as of the moment you iterate it.

You can add it to a ListBox like this:

```
AvailableTimesListbox.DataSource = AvailableTimeSlots
```

or like this:

```
For Each item As String In AvailableTimeSlots
    AvailableTimesListbox.Items.Add(item)
Next
```

or like this:

```
AvailableTimesListbox.Items.AddRange(AvailableTimeSlots.ToArray())
```

Comment: `AvailableTimesListbox.DataSource = AvailableTimeSlots.ToList()`

Comment: @Jimi Noooo! That does extra work and allocates extra memory for your list. There's no need for this. You can assign an IEnumerable as a datasource directly without calling .ToList().

Comment: The DataSource of a ListBox needs to be an IList. Otherwise, you could also use a Dictionary as DataSource (without calling `[Dictionary].ToList()`, I mean).

Comment: In the above, I manually populate the time slots: BookedTimeSlots As New List(Of String) From {"08h00-09h00", "10h00-11h00", "12h00-13h00", "16h00-17h00", "18h00-19h00"}. I am trying to populate the BookedTimeSlots Object from my database with the method. DTCurrentBookingsTableAdapter.FillObject(DsEventBooking13.DTCurrentBookings, MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString) . 
I am getting "0 " being returned instead of the time slots in the SQL query. My query returns the desired time slots. –

Comment: That sounds like a different question. But you can populate a list direct from a database result. You don't need to translate to an array first.